# Why does subscription to Application.ThreadException swallow the exception?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, events, exception

Suppose I have an exception throw in the message loop:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("yehaaaa!!!!");
    }
```

By default, this throws & displays the generic error dialog to user. (that's what I want)

However if I add the following subscription to Application.ThreadException:

```
    Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

    private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //_raygunClient.Send(e.Exception);
    }
```

Then the exception is swallowed.

Why?

& how can I have it throw to the user normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all right there in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,9b9af3f929d45314,references):

```
internal void OnThreadException(Exception t) {
    if (GetState(STATE_INTHREADEXCEPTION)) return;

    SetState(STATE_INTHREADEXCEPTION, true);
    try {
        if (threadExceptionHandler != null) {
            threadExceptionHandler(Thread.CurrentThread, new ThreadExceptionEventArgs(t));
        }
        else {
            if (SystemInformation.UserInteractive) {
                ThreadExceptionDialog td = new ThreadExceptionDialog(t);
```

If there is a handler it is invoked otherwise some standard code is run. If you want to show the standard dialog, use `ThreadExceptionDialog` and handle the DialogResult the same way. In my own code there is something to this effect, which seems to work:

```
private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = e.Exception;
    _Logger.Error(e.Exception, "An unhandled forms application exception occurred");

    // Show the same default dialog
    if (SystemInformation.UserInteractive)
    {
        using (ThreadExceptionDialog dialog = new ThreadExceptionDialog(exception))
        {
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return;
        }

        Application.Exit();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: So strange that simply subscribing to the event is enough to change the behavior - doesn't seem like the proper usage for the event pattern! Thanks.